# OAuth 2.0 OBO Grant type to convert Access to SAML Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, saml, azure-ad-graph-api

I hope everyone is safe and well !!

Need your expertise on this issue :

We are trying to convert Access token to SAML token using the OAuth OBO grant type. While we request to get SAML assertions using Access token we put details such as "resource = ABC" however in saml response it is getting as "audience = spn:ABC."

The issue is we get spn with a resource value in saml response that is not acceptable by our application team. Can you please shed some lights Why we are getting spn appended in SAML audience value?

Comment: Can you anyone shed some light?
I know this issue is related to URI ...If it is not URI then Microsoft will add SPN, however, is there a way to remove or get rid of this? I was going through some documentation and found that If I set somehow API like this "API://{api-app-id}/user_impersonation. " this would resolve this...however where to make changes on the end API or first app where the request is going to get a SAML token . not clear ??

Answer (score 0):

Following your own conclussions you need to change the *Application Id URI*. Take a look to step 9 from [Create an app registration in Azure AD for your App Service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-create-an-app-registration-in-azure-ad-for-your-app-service-app).

Comment: not working, already tried it. Opened case with MS they said its not supported until entity is a change at the application level.